# Check if command line arguments are in a correct form

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, try-catch, command-line-arguments

So if for instance my programm is correctly started like this:

```
java Test Tim;John;10;20
```

However I want to prevent users from entering something else than this form.

So whenever the command line arguments are not in the form `String;String;int;int` I want my programm to exit and print an error code.

I have no idea how to do this. For the case that if someone enters nothing I just used try catch with ArrayIndexOutofBounds but I dont know on how to particularly catch every possible command line arguments which is not in the correct form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it give you some idea:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        args = args[0].split(";");
        if (args.length != 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Program starts with parameters like this: (String, String, int, int)");
        }

        try {
            int firstInt = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Program starts with parameters like this: (OK, OK, int, int)");
        }

        try {
            int secondInt = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Program starts with parameters like this: (OK, OK, OK, int)");
        }
    }
```

Comment: the issue is the length one does not work since they are seperated with `;` and not with space.

Comment: I'll update the answer

Comment: Take a look at the first line in the method body. It should solve the problem.